# Can I split products into list

Tags: list-manipulation, products

Is there a way to take a term that is a product like x*y*z and split it into {x,y,z}?

Comment: `List @@ (x y z)`

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `FullForm` of `x y z` you find

```
FullForm[x y z]

(* Times[x, y, z] *)
```

That is, the head of the expression is `Times`, which you can just swap out for `List` using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) and [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) (`->`):

```
x y z /. Times -> List

(* {x, y, z} *)
```

**Edit 1: Using `Apply`**

@corey979's comment `List @@ (x y z)` performs the same function since (from the [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) docs) `f @@ expr` replaces the head of `expr` (in your case `Times`) by `f` (or `List`).

**Edit 2: In response to comment**

Suppose you have an monomial:

```
SeedRandom[123]
mon = Times @@ ({x, y, z}^RandomInteger[3, 3])

(* x y^3 z *)
```

Then using the same idea as above, you can do

```
mon /. Times | Power -> List

(* {x, {y, 3}, z} *)
```

and, using this as a list of arguments for [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html)

```
Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ (mon /. Times | Power -> List)]

(* {x, y, y, y, z} *)
```

In anticipation of your next question, suppose you have a polynomial:

```
SeedRandom[123]
poly = Total[Times @@ ({x, y, z}^#) & /@ RandomInteger[3, {4, 3}]]

(* x^2 y^2 + x y^2 z + z^2 + y^2 z^2 *)
```

and you want to listify each term. Then you can do:

```
Flatten /@ 
 Map[ConstantArray @@ # &, poly /. Plus | Times | Power -> List, {-2}]

(* {{x, x, y, y}, {x, y, y, z}, {z, z}, {y, y, z, z}} *)
```

(This will also work on a single monomial, but you have to enclose it in an extra list, i.e.: `{mon}`. Otherwise `Flatten` doesn't know what to do.)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with squared variables so it creates two of that element or no?

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan See my update. Also, are you aware that you can upvote and accept answers? See [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.